# Cross Domain issue in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, cross-domain

I have a web application that runs with backbone.js

I am using backbone models and separate REST API for database interactions.

Everything works well in my server. However i have to deploy it in clients AWS server and in that the webservice is in one EC2 instance and the backbone web files are in another instance. This is causing a cross domain error which i cannot resolve.

In jquery ajax i have used crossDomain:true and datatype:jsonp to resolve this issue.

But is there any method like this to resolve this issue in backbone.js? I understand backbone methods (save,fetch,delete) are all jquery-ajax calls but i cannot find a way to get over this issue in backbone.js

Error in console :

```
OPTIONS domain1.com/webservice_dev/profile/Login 
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
jquery.js:9597 XMLHttpRequest cannot load domain2.com/webservice_dev/profile/Login.
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Any guidance would be of great help.

Comment: Error in console : 

OPTIONS http://domain1.com/webservice_dev/profile/Login Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. jquery.js:9597
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain2.com/webservice_dev/profile/Login. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to acknowledge the Content-Type header in it's response to the preflight (OPTIONS) request.  This is due the fact that the underlying request is of a Content-Type other than text/plain, multipart/form-data, or application/x-www-form-urlencoded.